# Increased water heater temp and now T&P valve leakes

Tags: water-heater

I increased the temperature of the water heater and now every once in a while the T&P hose/pipe will drip. Was I supposed to adjust something there as well?
I ensured that the temperature on both panels was the same.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have an expansion tank? You might need one, or yours might need to be replaced if it's not working right.

Comment: No, no expansion tank. Would bringing the temperature back down fix it?

Comment: The higher the temperature, the higher the pressure.  Might just be you are at the edge for the pressure release, or the valve is weak and needs replacing.

Comment: If it was right on the edge of leaking before and you pushed it over the edge by turning it up, turning it down might help, but an expansion tank would allow it to be turned up and not leak...

Comment: Is that difficult to add? I don't mind some DIYs but don't have too much confidence in larger things like that.

Comment: @BMorin I wouldn’t say it’s difficult. How big (many gallons / litres) is your hot water tank. Is the plumbing in your house PEX or Copper or, heavens to Betsy, poly-b?

Comment: It's a 50 gallon tank. As for the plumbing... insert blank look here... Not sure. The house is a KB home built 10 yrs ago. Not sure what they use as standard.

Comment: I want to apologize in advance for any lack of knowledge that would help you all answer me, or for any silly questions/answers. I've only recently become brave enough to start doing things like this, so, I'm not as informed as I'd like to be.... yet :)

Comment: Take a pic of the hot water tank and post it

Comment: Couldn't add the pic in the comments so I added it to the original post.

Comment: Take the insulation off the pipes and post a (focused) pic showing just the pipes. Also, putting the pic in the question is _exactly_ what you should do, so you're spot on there! Oddly, the valve on the water softener looks like CPVC, but the little bit of exposed, white pipe above the heater looks like PEX. It would be odd to find a mixture, but who knows...

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks! Just attached it.

Answer (score 2):

Water expands as it's heated. If there is something that acts as a check valve (most commonly a pressure reducing valve, (PRV) rather than a check valve as such, for a municipal supply) the expansion translates to a significant pressure rise unless there's something else to accept that extra volume without such a severe pressure rise. So, the pressure gets too high and your pressure relief valve opens.

The solution is a trapped air bubble, usually in the form of a small "bladder or diaphragm" type expansion tank. That has an air bubble on one side of a rubber membrane, and water on the other. The pressure rises, but not as severely because the air can be compressed, while water is effectively incompressible. Unless they have unfortunately positioned check valves, folks on well systems have the same function served by the larger pressure tank that serves the well pump, so they don't require one specifically for the water heater.

If there is no expansion tank, or the rubber separating the air from the water has failed, an expansion tank typically needs to be added or replaced.

It is generally not possible to set the temperature so high that the temperature part of the relief valve is actuated, unless the thermostats are defective, so it's almost always due to overpressure. If you have a pressure gauge you could observe its behavior, but many municipal supply water systems lack even a single pressure gauge. Typically you see the pressure rise significantly when a lot of hot water is used, and replaced by cold water in the heater, and then little or no water is used while that water heats up and expands.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do anything else in terms of adding anything (expansion tank) I'm not confident enough to do that myself and can't currently hire anyone. 
I initially took the temp up to 145, dropped it down to 137 or so when I saw the first dripping, and now to 128 after I saw the last one. If it stops now, is it safe to assume that it was just too hot? Or is is not safe to assume at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a potable water expansion tank. The size of the tank you need will depend on the size of your hot water tank and the supply pressure. You can measure the supply pressure by picking up a gauge like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-3-4-in-Plastic-Water-Pressure-Test-Gauge-DP-IWTG/100175467 and attaching it to an outside hose bib or the cold water supply connection for a clothes washing machine. Attach the gauge and leave it overnight. This will tell you how high the pressure might reach when the local water supply is at its lowest usage.

Then use this PDF https://www.watts.com/dfsmedia/0533dbba17714b1ab581ab07a4cbb521/20441-source/es-plt-pdf to size the expansion tank appropriately.  My guess is that PLT-5 is sufficient, but again that will depend on whether or not you have unusually high supply pressure.

Once you know the supply pressure, you will need to charge the expansion tank's air bladder to the same or slightly higher pressure using a pump -- a simple tire pump will do -- even a pump at a gas station if you don't have a pump yourself. Just make sure not to over or under inflate the air bladder or it will be ineffective. So if your street supply pressure is 50psi, inflate the expansion tank's air bladder to between 50 and 55psi.

In the same PDF, if you scroll down, you'll see an illustration of how to install the tank. You place it inline the cold water side entering your hot water tank.

With the PEX pipe you have in your attached photo, adding the tank inline should be relatively simple but you will need tools that you might not already have, like a PEX crimper and cutter.

Last thing to know-- make sure the tank is supported. So build a little shelf and strap the tank down with some steel banding.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help

Comment: If I'm not able to install that, or at least not for a while, would bringing the temp down to 125 be ok for now?

Comment: @BMorin yes you can turn the water temp down.

Comment: Phew! I will have to do that for now so that I don't create a ticking time bomb. Thank you so much for all your help!!

Comment: One more question... the manual said (for optimal first hour hot water) to have the bottom temperature at 120 and the top at 125 or 130... is that recommended also by those who work on them, or just by manufacturers to get them to die out faster? I've seen both sides of some recommending that they be the same and others saying otherwise.

Comment: It won't die out any faster if they are at a different temperature. The main thing to know with an electric hot water heater like yours is that both upper and lower heating elements never turn on at the same time. The upper element is more likely to be on when the hot water actively is being used since that's when cold water will enter the tank at the top. The bottom element is likely to come on to maintain a constant temperature while hot water is not being used in the house. I personally set the elements at different temperatures, and I set the upper element hotter.